# explain salesforce FlexQueue limit?

Tags: apex, batch, apex-flex-queue

related to:
https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/FlexQueue
and
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_apex_flex_queue.htm&language=en_US

In both linked pages, the documentation says "The Apex flex queue enables **you** to submit up to 100 batch jobs for execution". I'm tempted to tell each of my users that 'you' can submit 100 batches, but that might not be what SFDC meant.

I'm looking for confirmation that this per-Org, rather than something more granular and generous like per execution context.

Related to that, if I have several hundred users, and a UI with a button that says "submit batch", is the normal path for the code to query the queue, and reject the submission if there are already 100 pending batches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still only have 5 concurrent batch process running at one time. Salesforce (with the FlexQueue) have introduced a new status `Holding`, such that you can have (per org) a maximum of 100 jobs in `Holding`, and a maximum of 5 either `Queued`, `Preparing` (but not Holding) or `Processing`.

From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

> Holding Batch Jobs in the Apex Flex Queue
> With Apex Flex Queue, you can submit up to 100 batch jobs without getting an error.
>
> The outcome of Database.executeBatch is as follows.
>
> - The batch job is placed in the Apex flex queue, and its status is set
>   to Holding.
> - If the Apex flex queue has the maximum number of 100
>   jobs, Database.executeBatch throws a LimitException and doesn’t add
>   the job to the queue.
>
> When system resources become available, the system picks up the next
> job from the top of the Apex flex queue and moves it to the batch job
> queue. The system can process up to five queued or active jobs
> simultaneously for each organization. The status of these moved jobs
> changes from Holding to Queued. Queued jobs get executed when the
> system is ready to process new jobs. You can monitor queued jobs in
> the Apex Jobs page.

So, if you did flood the queue with multiple requests, you'd get a Limits exception, so its still worth checking the number of jobs prior to doing that.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I was hoping for something that expressed your parenthetical (per org) more explicitly.  If that's as direct as the documentation gets, I'll accept it.

Comment: Documentation never seems to mention per org and batch apex limits on the same page, but it is per org. More info here too https://na1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that's a very helpful link.  ...52 pages for a "quick reference" guide?!